# Related rates shadow problem - physically correct?

Tags: calculus

A very common related rates problem in calculus is that of the shadow. It goes as follows:

You have a lamp of height $H_1$ and a man of height $H_2<H_1$ walking away from the lamp at speed $s>0$; the lamp's light casts a shadow on the man. How fast is the shadow length increasing?

The conventional way to solve is to work with similar triangles and essentially derive the formula

$$\frac{s(t)}{x(t) + s(t)} = \frac{H_2}{H_1}$$ where $s(t)$ is the shadow length and $x(t)$ is the distance between the lamp and the man. With this, computing $s'$ is easy since $s \propto x$ and $x' = s$.

However, I disagree with the above formula. Intuitively, I feel that any model of such a situation should encapsulate the fact that if the man, say, leans on the lamp, the length of the shadow will be equal to to his height. That is,$$\frac{s(t)}{H_2} \to 1 \ \text{as} \ x(t) \to 0$$

regardless of the value of $H_1$ or $H_2$.

But in the model $s(t) \to 0$ as $x(t) \to 0$.

So, basically, my question is are these problems correct in the "real world" sense? Or are they idealized problems presented to calculus students thoughtlessly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your so-called "fact" is false. If the man is modelled as an ideal line segment, then clearly if the man is directly under the lamp, he casts a point shadow, which has length $0$. So it does fit with what you derived from the formula.

Also, in the real world your head is more like a ball, so even standing under the lamp will produce a circular shadow. If you want to measure the height of the shadow you'll have to decide how to take that into account.

Comment: Note also that just because an expression for some real-world problem has a limit at some parameter value does not mean that the limit value has a meaningful interpretation for that parameter value, unless there is some kind of continuity. Here for example the length of the projection of a line segment is continuous under continuous motion of the line segment.

Comment: Oh, I think maybe I'm visualizing the "lamp" wrong. I thought of it more as a "wall", so to speak,with beams of light protruding from it. Silly me.

Comment: @MathematicsStudent1122: No problem. I also added a point about the real-world shadow that you would surely be interested in. Say you model a person as a ball on a stick...